# What is "using namespace::std" in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

I am reading some code snippets from others and I find a line:

```
using namespace::std;
```

I suspect its purpose is `using namespace std;`, with some typos. But to my surprise the compiler accepts this code without any complaint. I build with:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 9.4.0

$ /usr/bin/g++ ${SRC} -std=c++11 -pthread -Wall -Wno-deprecated -o ${OUT}
```

I wonder why is this code valid, and what effects will it make? I suspect it is a bad practice.

Comment: Can you show this in the context of some actual code that compiles?

Comment: You can use `::` to signal that something is from the global namespace. `::std` means `std` nested in the global namespace, simple as that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'd expect a whitespace between `namespace` and `::`, so the confusion is justified.

Comment: Related: link to cppreference: [Qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) *"If there is nothing on the left hand side of the ::, the lookup considers only declarations made in the global namespace scope (or introduced into the global namespace by a using declaration). This makes it possible to refer to such names even if they were hidden by a local declaration:"*

Comment: I'd use whitespace as well, @Raildex. However, it's not necessary here. It is necessary in "using namespace", because without the space, it turns into a symbol/token. `::` is not part of the previous token though, so there is no separator necessary. Also, no whitespace is necessary in "::std", for the same reasons.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I question about this line of code only, I used to think it is a quite obvious syntax error. In fact you can add whatever valid context you want to pass the compilation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well, we usually use `::` to do resolution like `std::vector`, so I used to think this is an obvious syntax error. After reading the code again I feel ironic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace::std` is the same as `using namespace std;`

The `::` symbol is the scope resolution operator. When used without a scope name before it , it refers to the global namespace. This means that `std` is a top level namespace, and is not enclosed in another.

The spaces before and after the `::` are optional in this case because the lexer can deduce the tokens from the context.

For example, all of the following are valid:

```
namespace A { namespace notstd{} } // define my own namespaces A and A::notstd
using namespace::std; // the standard library std
using namespace A;
using namespace ::A;
using namespace::A;
using namespace A::notstd;
```

**Update:**

As noted in one of the comments, `using namespace ::std;` and `using namespace std;` may actually lead to different results if the statement comes inside another namespace which contains its own nested namespace `std`. See the following (highly unlikely) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace A {
    namespace std {
        int cout = 5;
    }
    using namespace std; 
    void f1() {
        cout++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A::f1();
    printf("%d\n",A::std::cout); // prints 6

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's equivalent to `using namespace ::std;` and also equivalent to `using namespace std;`. The `::` refers to the global namespace, and `std` is put in the global namespace indeed.

As the syntax of [using-directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives):

(emphasis mine)

> ```
> attr(optional) using namespace nested-name-specifier(optional) namespace-name ;
> ```
>
> ... ...
> nested-name-specifier -   a sequence of names and scope resolution
> operators ::, **ending with a scope resolution operator. A single ::
> refers to the global namespace**.
> ... ...

Comment: Within another namespace that, in turn, contains a namespace named `std`,  `using namespace std` and `using namespace ::std` would have different effects.